# Google Maps receive polygon coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, polygon

I use this example to draw polygon on google maps :

http://nettique.free.fr/gmap/toolbar.html

After drawing a polygon, I would like to read coordinates of polygon created by me. So, in file `mapToolbar.js` (which is part of above example from nettique.free.fr) in javascript function called `stopediting` (is run when I click on 'hand' button).

So, my solution to read those coordinates is somekind of loop which I read coordinates :

```
MapToolbar.features.shapeTab.shape_1.latLngs.b[0].b[i].ib - latitude

MapToolbar.features.shapeTab.shape_1.latLngs.b[0].b[i].jb - longitude
```

It works quite well, but my problem is that from time to time the suffix `ib` and `jb` change to for instance `Ya` and `Za`. I hope that you know what it means. I must change my code ;/ but i do not want to! ;)

Do you know how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapToolbar.features.shapeTab.shape_1 is a [`google.maps.Polygon`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#Polygon)-instance.

Use `getPath()` to retrieve the path and the method `forEach` to loop over the path:

```
  MapToolbar.features.shapeTab.shape_1.getPath().forEach(function(latLng,index){
    console.log('shape_1',index,latLng.toString());
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my mini project ;)